# Error establishing a database connection - Wordpress setup, everything else is working

Tags: database, mysql, apache, linux

Setting up a LAMP stack with Wordpress on a home machine and port forwarding so I can host it on the Internet.  Everything seems to have gone ok so far, except when I browse to the IP I see the error in the title.

Setting everything up on Ubuntu Server (CLI-only) and doing the work remotely via SSH from a different Ubuntu machine.  Ie. I SSH in and run commands or browse as necessary.  Wordpress is pointing to /var/www/html/wordpress.  phpinfo.php or any .html in the wordpress folder shows up fine when I browse to it.  I SWEAR db credentials are correct, and I set up the account with the proper authentication type.  I installed phpmyadmin and it works but it only shows one out of the five DB's that I see in mysql.  I am not sure why the db is not connected; I think there is a problem with the db and it is not readable but I'm not sure.

Let me know what config files I can provide to help.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: If your database user cannot read the database and tables that WP is installed to then no amount of WP changes or debugging will help, you need to fix the MySQL permissions so that the database user has the necessary access. You should test if this is the case. Eliminate "it should be fine" by testing so that it becomes "it is fine". Also keep in mind that WP can give this error even if the DB connects ok, but the contents are not ok. It does not provide a means of differentiating between the two situations from the browser though.

Comment: Also, questions need to be self contained, please remove the google drive link and embed the information in code blocks in your question, The database details and salts in your `wp-config.php` are also now compromised and insecure as they've been shared by you on the open web. You will need to change them and reset the passwords of any WordPress users on sites that share those salts

Answer (score 0):

Ended up re-creating the db accounts and it worked afterwards.